# Rationale for enable/disable function v.s. change_state?

Tags: c, embedded

I am implementing a driver for an accelerometer where I have to implement functions such as enable/disable low-power mode.

I can either write:

```
lis2dh12_low_power_enable();
lis2dh12_low_power_disable();
```

or:

```
lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(boolean_t enable);
```

The former solution is generally more readable, but it may creates extra code such as in this specific case:

```
void foo(boolean_t status) {
    if (status)
        lis2dh12_low_power_enable();
    else
        lis2dh12_low_power_disable();
}
```

Is there any rationale (MISRA like rules) for implementing such typical enable / disable functions?

Comment: As I see it, the _enable / disable functions_ are much more readable, but can lead to branch-prediction-failure so I guess it's readability vs efficiency

Comment: It was my guess too, and I am wondering if one can get both readability and efficiency

Comment: 3-4 instructions. Does it make any difference? How often do you do it . 20k times per sec? Imo it is absolutely secondary problem, and you can inline it, and it will be optimised better than most coders do.

Comment: @PeterJ In the embedded world, I am afraid it does :(

Comment: Really?  Changing the power mode ? How often do you call it to be a performance issue

Comment: it will be eventually very well optimised, nothing to worry about https://godbolt.org/g/SUYqQx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for implementing `lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(boolean_t enable);` as is and define the two others as macros around it, like:

```
#define lis2dh12_low_power_enable() lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(1)
```

---

BTW: `boolean_t` isn't C. Since C99 it's either the built-in type `_Bool` or the macro `bool` from `stdbool.h`.

Even more the suffix `_t` is reserved by POSIX for future types.

Comment: In this case why not `inline void lis2df12_low_power_enable() { lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(true); }`

Comment: @nowox because `inline` is just a suggestion to the compiler. For such a simple thing, you probably want to "force inlining", which can be achieved using a macro, as it's literally pasted into the source.

Comment: I wouldn't define the other two at all. Avoiding several ways to do the very same thing is good API design.

Comment: Thanks for the `boolean_t` information. I am going to use `bool` from this day on.

Comment: @Lundin: Good point! Still one (I?) could argue that the preprocessor is "just" the lazy typers friend, and with this not part of the *compiled* C code ... *ouch* ... so I don't! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly subjective. I can share my experience, but I can't list any formal sources. MISRA-C for example, does not concern itself with program design and efficiency.

In my experience, a function of the format `lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(boolean_t enable);` is generally preferred. You get one function less to keep track of and it reduces code size a tiny bit.

But more importantly, cases like your example with if-else, creates a branch, which leads to less effective code on many systems. Since functions like these are often just wrappers around `volatile` register access. And because of the `volatile`, the compiler may not necessarily be able to optimize away the branch.

In addition, the caller might have to keep track of if "the thing" is enabled or disabled, so there is often a boolean in the caller as well. It is then more convenient for the caller just to pass this variable on to your driver, rather than having to write an if-else.

Comment: In the past I've actually taken the decision to rewrite driver APIs just for the sake of changing from the former style to the latter. Makes the code simpler and faster both.

Comment: What terminology have you chosen? `change_state`? I am not satisfied with this one.

Comment: @nowox Most often `void something_enable (bool enable)`. Change state kind of implies that there are more than 2 states. Similarly, the getter function would be `bool something_is_enabled (void)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide `lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(boolean_t enable);` there's every possibility it will be implemented (possibly repeatedly!) as a helper or (worse) repeated code across the application of the form:

```
if (status)
    lis2dh12_low_power_enable();
else
    lis2dh12_low_power_disable();
```

So the `_enable()`\ `_disable()` version is an inevitable threat to DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself).

You can always code:

```
lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(B_TRUE);
```

or

```
lis2dh12_low_power_change_state(B_FALSE);
```

(Where `B_TRUE` and `B_FALSE` are constants) Which is cleaner.

Just to dismiss the performance question - I can't possibly imagine why an additional branch statement on code that changes the power level setting could conceivably affect anything. If you're banging the power setting there's something else wrong!

Indeed if the change state function can be inline any optimizer would 'see through' the calls with a constant and removed the branch where possible.

Comment: Why using `B_TRUE` instead of `true` ?

Comment: No big reason. Your question used `boolean_t` so I made up some assumption about what defined `true`. If you're not using `<stdbool.h>` then `true` is a not recommended choice because you might be incompatible with it. That might cause you or someone using your code down the line difficulty.